# Having issues with socket.io and Async queries

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to pass information from a database lookup through socket.io and I am having more troubles than I thought I would.

Here is the socket.io emit:

```
module.exports = (app, io) => {
  io.sockets.on('connect', async socket => {
    if (!socket.handshake.session.passport) {
      return socket.emit('redirect');
    }

    //Online
    console.log(Object.keys(app.online).length);
    //Load up
    await loadup(app, socket).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    await socket.emit('load up', loadup(app, socket));
}
```

(I tried multiple ways to get the desired data to show)

Here is the actual method:

```
const statHandler = require('./loadhandling/statload');
const User = require('../models/User');
module.exports = async (app, socket) => {
  let isOnline = app.online[socket.handshake.session.passport.user];
  if (!isOnline) return;
  // Start the loadup process
  User.findById(socket.handshake.session.passport.user, (err, user) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    let userdata = user.meta;
    statHandler(userdata);
    return userdata;
  });
};
```

I've always seemed to struggle in these situations for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fumble my through this:

Socket.io

```
module.exports = (app, io) => {
  io.sockets.on('connect', async socket => {
    if (!socket.handshake.session.passport) {
      return socket.emit('redirect');
    }

    //Online
    console.log(Object.keys(app.online).length);
    //Load up
    const load = await loadup(app, socket);
    await socket.emit('load up', load);
}
```

Method:

```
const statHandler = require('./loadhandling/statload');
const User = require('../models/User');
module.exports = async (app, socket) => {
  let isOnline = app.online[socket.handshake.session.passport.user];
  if (!isOnline) return;
  // Start the loadup process
  const thisUser = await User.findById(
    socket.handshake.session.passport.user,
    (err, user) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  ).then(user => {
    let userdata = user.meta;
    statHandler(userdata);
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      res({ userdata });
    });
  });

  return await thisUser;
};
```

I'm sure theres a more efficient way, but I don't feel like finding one. Hope this helps someone in the future.